# Can I set a challenge using Box-256?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rules

**Re-edited** for further clarify:

http://box-256.com/ is an on-line game in which one codes in a form of assembly to solve the puzzles presented on there.

Can we ask questions on this site which are competitions based on the levels on http://box-256.com/ - such as "Who can solve the 'BIG SQAURE' level in the least amount of instructions?"

The reason I ask is because the contest is technically about how well the contestants can "play a game" but that game is to program in assembly so to me would seem on-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are programming languages?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the feedback, I have updated the question for clarity.

Comment: I was going to write a follow-up comment, but got distracted. The other issue which seems to me to be mixed in with "What is a programming language?" is "[Can I write a question which asks for answers in a given language?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2255/194)". Does that link answer your question?

Comment: I feel like this question is a bit unclear, do you mean something like: "Could I create a challenge where one should write a program to output some box-256 assembly that would do some action in the game?" If that is what you mean I think the answer depends on their policies. It should be fine to ask something like that here unless box-256's owners are against it.

Comment: Here it is: Related: [manufactoria](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufactoria)

Answer (score 1):

OK thanks for the input all, I think the answer here  is that questions based on Box256 can be asked, I have asked one and  it has sort-of-worked:

[Box-256 Assembly - BIG SQUARE II](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77795/box-256-assembly-big-square-ii)

However there have been issues on how to score the answers so I am going to start another Meta question to come up with a fair and easily understandable scoring system.